# I would like to swap every second character of a string

Tags: java, string

I would like to swap every second character of a string like so:

```
welcome -> ewclmoe
```

How can I do this?

Comment: you need to try something first

Comment: What are the rules of conversion? I would start by using a StringBuilder. Then add characters to the StringBuilder based on the rules of your conversion.

Comment: Are you sure you wouldn't like to do it yourself? It seems like a good exercise.

Comment: Done. It wasn't all that hard. I'm sure you can do it too. Here, I'll share the loop: `for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i += 2) {`

Comment: `ewclmoe` to Stack Overflow `:-)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below code works...
check it out...

```
public static void swapCharacter(String s) {
    char[] a = s.toCharArray();
    char temp;
    for(int i=0; i<a.length-1;i+=2)
    {
        temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[i+1];
        a[i+1] = temp;
    }
    System.out.println(new String(a));
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    swapCharacter("welcome");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to build the output with a `StringBuilder`. Iterate the even indices of the original `String`. First append the next odd character (if there is one), then take the even character. Like,

```
String s = "welcome";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i += 2) {
    if (i + 1 < s.length()) {
        sb.append(s.charAt(i + 1));
    }
    sb.append(s.charAt(i));
}
System.out.println(sb);
```

Outputs (as requested)

```
ewclmoe
```